# Sort by reverse order mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi, I am trying to return my query in backwards order from which it was created. 

The docs are a little unclear on how to use the sort method: 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_array_MongooseArray.sort

Here is my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'), 
    Schema     = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId   = Schema.Types.ObjectId;

let PostSchema = new Schema({
    title      : String,
    description: String,
    image      : String,
    tags       : [String],
    original_poster: {  
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    date: {
       type: Date,
       default: new Date()
   }
})



module.exports = mongoose.model('Post',PostSchema);
```

I have run,

```
db.posts.find().sort({date:-1}).pretty()
```

For example, if my model was a 'Post' model and my first post was 'hello world' and my second post was 'this is a post'. I would like to see:

```
 ['this is a post', 'hello world']
```

However, what I am actually seeing is `['hello world','this is a post']`

Comment: There is no `date` field in the schema. You are sorting by a field that is equally `undefined` in all documents.

Answer (score 8):

**Figured out the answer**

in posts schema add:

```
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
```

then `db.posts.find().sort({date:-1}).pretty()` will yield the posts sorted from most recent to least recent

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a creation timestamp in your schema and sort by its key.

```
let PostSchema = new Schema({
    title      : String,
    description: String,
    date       : Date, // Here is your date
    image      : String,
    tags       : [String],
    original_poster: {  
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    }
})
```

and when you insert a document, use:

```
date: new Date()
```